# Curl + sTunnel returning 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, openssl, stunnel

i know this question may have been asked previously, seen some posts on it but no definite solution given. I have been successfully connecting and making calls to a server via curl using stunnel until recently when it started throwing this error:

> 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

The server address is 127.0.0.1:5555/Exec. I can successfully connect from my local machine but it fails when requests are from my Ubuntu server.